# How to migrate data from dolphindb to python numpy?

Tags: python, database, numpy, dolphindb

I have some data in dolphindb, such as：

```
a = 1                // int
st  = "stringx"      // string
m1=1..9$3:3          // matrix
vec = 1 2 3 4 5 6    // vector
```

I want to use them in numpy, what should I do? What kind of numpy object they will be convert to?

Answer (score 1):

when you download these data using DolphinDB Python API, it will be automatically converted into numpy

```
    import dolphindb as ddb
    s = ddb.session()
    s.connect("localhost",8848, "admin","123456")
    s.run("vec=1..6")
    vec=s.run("vec")

    >>> vec
    array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)
```